# Grails 4 upgrade

Tags: grails

I am upgrading to grails 4 from grails 3 but when running the i got the following error

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field urlMappings in org.grails.web.mapping.servlet.UrlMappingsErrorPageCustomizer required a bean of type 'grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings' in your configuration.
```

pls help...

Comment: I would need to see the build file to know for sure but it is quite likely that you have a dependency missing, or an incompatible version of some dependency being pulled in.

Comment: Alot of plugins were maintained by the community for Grails3. Grails4 has decided that the community is no longer going to be submitting plugins so alot of them no longer work in Grails4. Grails3 is the last 'community' edition. So you may have to stick to Grails 3... which is probably better since Grails4 ditched Spring context and others Spring methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

Having url without starting slash caused this error for me.

```
"oauth/azure/callback"(controller: 'azureOAuth', namespace: 'v1') {
  action = [GET: 'callback']
}
```

I just added / and error was gone.